# Why doesn't numpy allow array multiplication by scalars?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I assumed that `@` was shorthand for the `dot` method.  What motivated the design decision to block multiplication by an array with shape `()`?

```
In [6]: a = np.ones((2,1))

In [7]: a.dot(1)
Out[7]:
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.]])

In [8]: a @ 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-398cff4c0ec9> in <module>()
----> 1 a @ 1

ValueError: Scalar operands are not allowed, use '*' instead
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@` is the infix operator for [`matmul`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html), not `dot` (note that the two functions are not equivalent for higher-dimensional arrays (higher than 2D)).

No explicit reason for rejecting scalars as operands is stated in the documentation, but it seems probable that the motivation stems from [PEP 0465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) which originally proposed the introduction of `@` as an infix operator for Python 3.5. From the 'semantics' section:

> 0d (scalar) inputs raise an error. Scalar `*` matrix multiplication is a mathematically and algorithmically distinct operation from matrix `@` matrix multiplication, and is already covered by the elementwise `*` operator. Allowing scalar `@` matrix would thus both require an unnecessary special case, and violate TOOWTDI ["There's Only One Way To Do It"].

Comment: Funny that rule is something a Python developer would write, not a numpy one.  The numpy approach is to turn the scalar into an array and proceed.  Most numpy changes aren't ruled by peps.

Comment: I guess that PEP was written mainly with numerical libraries specifically in mind (NumPy chief among them). The author is Nathaniel J. Smith, who I think contributes frequently to NumPy's development.

Comment: @hpaulj: The PEP was pretty much written by numpy developers (in collaboration with other numerical libraries); python-dev mostly rubber-stamped it. You can see more of the history in the [references at the bottom](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/#discussions-of-this-pep), or [check that that text was present in the very first version that the upstream python developers saw](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2014-March/027053.html).

Comment: @NathanielJ.Smith: Thanks for the link!  That explains the last of my questions.

Comment: I guess as a further note with actual content :-): numpy in general doesn't just turn scalars into arrays willy-nilly; most operations follow some very simple deterministic rules. What `dot` does with scalars is weird -- it effectively promotes a scalar into a square matrix with the scalar on the diagonal and zeros everywhere else. There's no other scalar->array promotion in numpy that acts even vaguely like that. So should `@` do what `dot` does, should it broadcast, or... what? There's no great answer, and `scalar @ matrix` is pointless anyway (you can just use `*` instead), so we punted.